# How to use parallel looping?

Tags: php, foreach, logic

I am confused as to how I can output my two object in parallel. This is my situation. In my `contract` table, it has a parent_id on itself (each contract can have have maximum of one child contract), and then every contract has `perk`. **So i am aiming to output this**:

```
Old Contract Perks            Perks               New Contract Perks
1 ticket per year       Ticket Entitlement        2 ticket per year
30 days vacation        Vacation Entitlement      45 days vacation
...                     ...                       ...
```

and this is my code:

```php
PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, $x, '', "Old Contract Perks", 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, '', '', "Perks Name", 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, '', '', "New Contract Perks", 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
foreach ($this->contract->perks as $key => $perk) {
    foreach ($this->getParentContract($this->contract->parent_id)->perks as $parent_perk) {
        PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, $x, '', $parent_perk->allotment, 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
        PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, '', '', $perk->perk_name, 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
        PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, '', '', $perk->allotment, 1, 1, 1, true, 'C', true);
    }
}
```

but my out put, when run, is like this:

```
Old Contract Perks            Perks               New Contract Perks
1 ticket per year       Ticket Entitlement        2 ticket per year
30 days vacation        Vacation Entitlement      2 ticket per year
1 ticket per year       Ticket Entitlement        45 days vacation
30 days vacation        Vacation Entitlement      45 days vacation
...                     ...                       ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the parent contract has the same keys as the child, you can use the `$key` value from the `child` to access the corresponding parent perk:

```
$parent_perks = $this->getParentContract($this->contract->parent_id)->perks;
foreach ($this->contract->perks as $key => $perk) {
    PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, $x, '', $parent_perks[$key]->allotment, 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
    PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, '', '', $perk->perk_name, 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
    PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, '', '', $perk->allotment, 1, 1, 1, true, 'C', true);
}
```

If the contracts may have different numbers of perks, you need to find which has the most perks and use that to control the loop:

```
$parent_perks = array_values($this->getParentContract($this->contract->parent_id)->perks);
$perks = array_values($this->contract->perks);
$count_perks = max(count($parent_perks), count($perks));
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_perks; $i++) {
    PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, $x, '', $parent_perks[$i]->allotment ?? '', 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
    PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, '', '', $perks[$i]->perk_name ?? $parent_perks[$i]->perk_name, 1, 0, 1, true, 'C', true);
    PDF::writeHTMLCell(50, 0, '', '', $perks[$i]->allotment ?? '', 1, 1, 1, true, 'C', true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It now works, but what if the parent contract has, let say 3 perks and the new contract has 5 perks?

Comment: @AnirudhLou are the perks integer indexed arrays starting from 0?

Comment: Nope, i didn't index it. but it has its own unique id.

Comment: @AnirudhLou I think my edit should work for unequal numbers. btw you shouldn't accept an answer until you are completely happy as it will make it less likely that other users will answer the question.